# Issue with receiving response from 127.0.0.1 with udp client in python

Tags: python, udp

I'm working through the book 'Black Hat Python' and am having issues with a UDP connection to 127.0.0.1 on port 80. I'm fairly new to this stuff so it's not something I can simply just sit down and troubleshoot quickly and efficiently, so I was hoping someone may be able to point out an error or maybe it's just my setup. I am testing this in Kali VM with VMware Fusion. The socket stays open and waits for a response, but never receives one.

```
import socket

target_host = "127.0.0.1"
taget_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client.sendto("AAABBBCCC", (target_host, taget_port))

data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)

print data
```

Comment: Are you sure that server receives your message ("AABBBCCC") ?

Comment: I'm trying to check that right now using Wireshark, but like I said I'm new to this so I'm not entirely sure what to look for other than the sniff through the packets and see if I see mine.

Comment: What exactly are you using to receive the message ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that? I assume the code above works by opening a socket to 127.0.0.1 (my machine) through port 80 (HTTP) which is sending the message "AAABBBCCC". Then the `client.recvfrom()` call should return the data (should be "AAABBBCCC") and the address it received it from (127.0.0.1). When I debug the code, it never get past the `client.sendto()` call for some reason. I've tried changing the port to one not connected with a protocol, and also changing to 0.0.0.0 based on other answers i've seen online.

Comment: `data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)` will not catch the message you are trying to send, instead it will wait for the server to respond which apparently you didn't even start. Please read [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) on how to establish the communication between sockets.

Comment: Is the program trying to talk to itself? In other words, is the `.recvfrom()` intended to receive the very message that the `.sendto()` sends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your architecture of having a client and a server exist in the same thread is very unusual. I would not recommend it.

Nevertheless, your program will work the way you want if you `.bind()` the socket to the target address:

```
import socket

target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_port = 8000

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client.bind((target_host, target_port))
client.sendto("AAABBBCCC", (target_host, target_port))

data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)

print data
```

Comment: In the book of following that is how is demonstrating the different TCP/IP protocols. That does work, however why does he have the HTTP port specified? Will this not ever work regardless of what I do?


Edit: Changed the port to 80 and it seemed to work that time. Maybe it's just a typo in his example because I have seen almost every example of udp client/server having to bind the socket to the target address.

Comment: 1) In the book you are using, I'm sure that each example is given as a pair of programs: one client and one server. In order to test the operation of the client program, one must also run the server program (perhaps in another command window). It seems from your question that you want your client program to run without the benefit of a server program. Adding `.bind()` allows your program to behave simultaneously as both client and server. 2) I only changed the port number for my convenience. It should work equally well with `80`.

Comment: Well I appreciate the help.

Comment: I also had this problem, still couldnt figure out why for some people the code seems to work without bind. Dont know if it could be related to python/socket versions. If you have a clue please comment here. Anyway thank you very much

Comment: The book that the original poster is using is "Black Hat Python", available through the following link: https://olinux.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/python.pdf The code example originates from the second chapter, on network basics.